# TransformerException: Unknown Error In XPath

Tags: java, android, dom, xpath

I'm using the `org.w3c.dom` library to store XML `Elements` and `Documents` in an Item class that I made. At times I need to use `setAttribute` to configure the `Elements` for later parsing (done by a server written in .NET). I originally used `JDOM`, but due to XPath and `selectSingleNode` being deprecated, it no longer had the functionality I need.

My variables are declared as:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db;
Document outDom = null;
db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
outDom = (Document) db.parse("<Empty/>");
Node fault_node = null;
```

And the error comes from the line:

```
fault_node = (Node) xp.evaluate(Item.XPathFault, outDom, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

This is in another class than Item (`HttpServerConnection`, if it matters) but `Item.XPathFault` is declared in Item as

```
public static final String XPathFault = "/" + Soap.EnvelopeBodyFaultXPath;
```

And Soap contains the definitions

```
static final String SoapEnvUri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
private static final String SoapNamespaceCheck = "namespace-uri()='" + SoapEnvUri + "' or namespace-uri()=''";
static final String EnvelopeXPath = "*[local-name()='Envelope' and (" + SoapNamespaceCheck + ")]";
static final String BodyXPath = "*[local-name()='Body' and (" + SoapNamespaceCheck + ")]";
static final String FaultXPath = "*[local-name()='Fault' and (" + SoapNamespaceCheck + ")]";
static final String EnvelopeBodyXPath = EnvelopeXPath + "/" + BodyXPath;
static final String EnvelopeBodyFaultXPath = EnvelopeBodyXPath + "/" + FaultXPath;
```

The problem is that when I run the program on an Emulator, I get the error:

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown error in XPath.
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:295)
```

What I want to be getting out of the XPath.evaluate function is a selectSingleNode, which is deprecated in JDOM2 and nonexistent in w3c.dom. Though to be honest, I'm not sure that I'm even using the right function. But I know *where* the error is coming from, but I can't figure out *why*.

## **EDIT: I HAVE FOUND AN ANSWER**

It turns out my issue was with the code `db.parse("<Empty/>");` and other similar statements.

I misunderstood the functionality of `parse`. When passed a String, it assumes the String is a path/location of an XML file to be read. This resulted in an error when I was passing the actual XML as a String to the method. If `parse` is passed an `InputStream`, it reads the content of the stream as XML.

I fixed my program by changing

```
outDom = (Document) db.parse("<Empty/>");
```

to the slightly longer

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("<Empty />".getBytes());
Document outDom = (Document) builder.parse(is);
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of XPathFault after all of that concatenation takes place? Perhaps that would provide some insight.

Comment: XPathFault returns as `/*[local-name()='Envelope' and (namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' or namespace-uri='')]/*[local-name()='Body' and (namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' or namespace-uri='')]/*[local-name()='Fault' and (namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope' or namespace-uri()='')]`


What I want to be doing is a selectSingleNode operation,but that function is deprecated in JDOM and nonexistent in w3DOM.

Answer (score 0):

XPath has not be deprecated in JDOM, you just have to use different classes:

```
  XPathFactory xpfac = XPathFactory.instance();
  XPathExpression<Element> xp = xpfac.compile("//title", Filters.element());
  List<Element> results = xp.evaluate(doc);
```

The new classes are there to support generics.